# Question about complex numbers

Tags: complex-numbers

Proof that if $z = 1$, then $|z-w| = |1- \overline{w}z|$, $\forall w \in$ $\mathbb{C}$

My attempt below:

$(z-w)\overline{(z-w)} = |z-w|^2$
$(z-w)\overline{(z-w)} = (z-w)(\overline{z}-\overline{w}) = |z|^2 -z\overline{w} -\overline{z\overline{w}} +|w|^2 = |z|^2 - 2Re(z\overline{w}) + |\overline{w}|^2*1 = 1 - 2Re(z\overline{w}) + |\overline{w}|^2*|z|^2 = 1 - 2Re(z\overline{w}) + |\overline{w}z|^2 = 1 - 2Re(\overline{w}z) + |\overline{w}z|^2$

$|z-w|^2 = 1 - 2Re(\overline{w}z) + |\overline{w}z|^2$

I was trying identfiy a remarkable product, but I didn't have success. Someone can help me with this question?

Answer (score 2):

In fact, if $|z|=1$, then $\def\o#1{\overline #1}|z-w|=|1-\o w z|$.

**Proof**.  Use the fact that a complex number and its conjugate have the same modulus.  If $|z|=1$, then
$$|z-w|=|\o z-\o w|=|z||\o z-\o w|=|z\o z-\o wz|=|1-\o w z|\ .$$

Answer (score 1):

if |z| = 1 then

$1-\bar z w=z\bar z -\bar zw=\bar z(z-w)$

Taking Modulus ,

$|1-\bar z w|=|\bar z (z-w)|=|\bar z||z-w|=|z-w|$

Answer (score 0):

Assuming  $|z|=1$

$$|z-w|=|\bar z-\bar w|=|z||\bar z-\bar w|=|z(\bar z-\bar w)|=||z|^2-\bar wz|$$

Now $z\cdot\bar z=|z|^2=1^2$